# YouTube API returns wrong video duration

Tags: youtube-data-api

I'm using the YouTube API to get the duration of videos. However, the API response does not correspond to video length.

Example:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g5xNzUA5Qf8

Length on YouTube 3:33
[Screen shot of video on YouTube](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f7j1j.png)

Duration in YouTube API: 1 day, 2 hours 34 minutes and 17 seconds

```json
    {
      "kind": "youtube#video",
      "etag": "tWwii1RezGsoNlQtpFjI00I5gog",
      "id": "g5xNzUA5Qf8",
      "contentDetails": {
        "duration": "P1DT2H34M17S",
        "dimension": "2d",
        "definition": "sd",
        "caption": "false",
        "licensedContent": false,
        "contentRating": {},
        "projection": "rectangular"
      }
    }
```

Other example:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KZeXI0iHsAA

3 minutes vs 1 hour

Is this a YouTube API bug, or is there something I don't understand?
I didn't find anyone reporting a similar problem.

Comment: I have logged a bug for this in the meanwhile: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/218088923

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that one more time YouTube Data API v3 doesn't work as documented.

I would recommend you to use my [open-source](https://github.com/Benjamin-Loison/YouTube-operational-API/blob/9ea46f8a389ba3ca9b667d02b08ea26558d3d9c5/videos.php#L90) [YouTube operationnal API](https://yt.lemnoslife.com) at https://yt.lemnoslife.com/videos?part=contentDetails&id=g5xNzUA5Qf8

It will return you the correct duration in seconds and not in the [ISO 8601 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) (if you really need this format please leave a comment).

Comment: Are there any rate limits? And how does your API get the correct value?

Comment: I haven't seen for the moment any rate limit for the moment, if you encounter any, please tell me how to reproduce the problem and I would investiguate. My API uses the YouTube webview user interface API, it's not documented and not official but I have reverse-engineered it.